# `head` and `tail` in ruby for strings and objects?

Tags: ruby

I was going through some large strings today and suddenly thought, "I'd like to just `head` or `tail` out this stuff."

I am able to simply use: `"some large string...".[0..9]` to show the first 10 chars of the string and similarly for tail (`[-10..-1]`) I suppose, but are there any options already done so that we can simply do:

`"string".head(10)` and `"string".tail(50)`?

Similarly, I'd like to see something like this be able to parse object structures generally.  Do I need to build my own library or is this already done somehow in standard libraries that I'm simply overlooking?

Comment: I've reached for `first(n)` and `last(n)` for strings more than once, only to find they're not there.  I don't know why; they'd be handy.  Those methods exist for arrays and ranges, but not hashes, where they wouldn't make much sense, as it's generally not good practice to rely on the ordering of the elements of a hash (which has only be guaranteed, in a sense, since Ruby v1.9). You'd have to look at it on an object-by-object basis.

Comment: Just for fun, here's some bad ideas: `"abcdefg".chars.first(3).join`, `"abcdefg"[/.{3}/]`.  But seriously, just use [activesupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb) like @nick-veys said.

Comment: `String` is just string. It's not an enumerable. Of course, one can transform a string into a char sequence or byte sequence, whatever.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: a string is not an iterator, it is factory of iterators. What should `some_string.first(3)` return? The first 3 characters? Glyphs? Columns? Codepoints? Bytes? Lines? Words? Paragraphs? Sentences?

Answer (score 1):

The [`first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-last) and [`last`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-last) methods exist in Rails' [ActiveSupport string extensions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/access.rb), but not the core libraries unfortunately.  You could always bring in ActiveSupport as a gem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little clunky, but in plain Ruby (without ActiveSupport) you can do this:

```
str = "this is a test"

str.chars.first(10).join
# => "this is a "

str.chars.last(10).join
# => " is a test"
```

Comment: The question is whether such methods exist, not how they could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

For strings you can use Ruby's [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) for this by providing the head chars count:

```
head, tail = "A quite long string that needs to find its head and tail".
  scan(/(.{12})(.+)/).flatten
```

The above code will match any first 12 characters and the remaining ones. Thus giving:

```
head #=> "A quite long"
tail #=> " string that needs to find its head and tail"
```

For anything else that can be used as an array you can use [Array#slice!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21)

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
tail = a.dup
head = tail.slice!(0,4)
```

which will give

```
tail #=> [5,6]
head #=> [1,2,3,4]
```